# Able to select from table, but not count rows

Tags: mysql

I've been running a tiny MySQL db for a throwaway project, and dumped the file for a coworker, who was able to get everything running.

We're using C#, and running two queries, one of which does:

```
SELECT * FROM someview LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

and the other does:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM someview;
```

I would be using SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * and FOUND_ROWS(), but that's apparently not supported outside of stored procs with the MySQLDataReader.

Anyway, the problem is, both queries work fine on my system. On his, the first works just fine, but the SELECT COUNT(*) statement fails with the following error:

```
Error Code: 1356. View 'db.someview' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
```

We checked the results of SHOW GRANTS, and have identical permissions, both running as the same user (root). It's not a C# problem, because the exact same thing happens if he runs it in the MySQL command line or Workbench.

He's also able to issue SELECT COUNT(*) queries successfully against any other table or view in the DB, including a view that the first view depends on. It's just this one particular view, where he can SELECT *, but not SELECT COUNT(*).

Has anyone else experienced anything similar?

Server version: 5.5.29 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

**EDIT**: Here are the two view creation scripts, stripped down to the relevant parts that still have the problem, based on [Evan Miller's How Not To Sort By Average Rating](http://evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html).

```
CREATE VIEW
    product_rating_counts
AS
SELECT
    p.id AS productId,
    sum(case when (r.rating = 1) then 1 else 0 end) AS 1_star,
    sum(case when (r.rating = 2) then 1 else 0 end) AS 2_star,
    sum(case when (r.rating = 3) then 1 else 0 end) AS 3_star,
    sum(case when (r.rating = 4) then 1 else 0 end) AS 4_star,
    sum(case when (r.rating = 5) then 1 else 0 end) AS 5_star,
    sum(case when (r.rating < 3) then 1 else 0 end) AS negative_ratings,
    sum(case when (r.rating > 3) then 1 else 0 end) AS positive_ratings,
    sum(case when (r.rating = 3) then 1 else 0 end) AS neutral_ratings
FROM
    product p
INNER JOIN
    review r
ON
    p.id = r.productId
GROUP BY
    p.id;

CREATE VIEW
    ranked_products
AS
SELECT
    p.id AS ID,
    p.SKU AS SKU,
    p.Name AS Name,
    prc.1_star,
    prc.2_star,
    prc.3_star,
    prc.4_star,
    prc.5_star,
    prc.positive_ratings AS Positive,
    prc.negative_ratings AS Negative,
    prc.neutral_ratings AS Neutral,
    ((prc.positive_ratings + 1.9208) / (prc.positive_ratings + prc.negative_ratings) -
               1.96 * SQRT((prc.positive_ratings * prc.negative_ratings) / (prc.positive_ratings + prc.negative_ratings) + 0.9604) /
                      (prc.positive_ratings + prc.negative_ratings)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (prc.positive_ratings + prc.negative_ratings))
    AS ci_lower_bound
FROM
    product p
INNER JOIN
    product_rating_counts prc
ON
    p.id = prc.productId
WHERE
    (prc.positive_ratings + prc.negative_ratings) > 0
ORDER BY
    ci_lower_bound DESC;
```

So what's working for me is:

```
SELECT * FROM ranked_products LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ranked_products;
```

But for my coworker, the first query returns just fine, while the second gives him the invalid tables/columns/permissions error.

We're probably going to scrap this anyway, but I hate not knowing why something's not working.

Comment: Can you post your definition for `someview`?

Comment: @AndyRefuerzo: Updated with the view definitions. For sake of clarity, a Rating has a product ID and an integer rating 1-5, and a Product has an ID, SKU, and Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search yields the following results:

[This documented bug#59005 (5.1.36-5.5.9)](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=59005) happens when there is `NULL` in the result set in the view

While [this bug#60295 (5.1.57-5.6.3)](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60295) happens when tables in the view have the same column name

On the other hand, [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maria/+bug/1006160/comments/5) suggests that you could be running into a variation of [bug#33000 (5.0-5.6.6)](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33000) and that a viable solution is to run `FLUSH TABLES`

Another solution to try can be found here: [Views and Privileges](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ogsa-dai/wiki/MySQLUseful#Viewsandprivileges)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give those a shot in the morning.

Comment: I'm certain there were no nulls in the result set, nor duplicate names. The view was freshly created, so doubtful it needed to be flushed. I'm guessing it was the last one you mentioned, but haven't gotten to test it yet. I say guess, because my coworker dropped the "ORDER BY" clause from the second view, and it now works. I'm guessing since he dropped and redefined the view, it fixed the privileges, though I'm not sure why that didn't work when he dropped them and created them from the DDL earlier. In any case, it appears to be fixed, so thanks for the links.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as `totalcount` FROM ranked_products LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: This doesn't address the mysterious inability to run the COUNT query on a different machine.